# What is the difference between horizontal scaling and distributed systems?

Tags: architecture, system, computer-science, distributed-computing, scaling

I am studying system design right now. I tried to research this, but the only thing I could find was a poorly explained answer on Quora.

1) What is the difference between horizontal scaling and distributed systems?

2) Does horizontal scaling imply a distributed system and why?

3) can vertical scaling also be considered a distributed system and why?

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for similar answers. After few readings and gained understanding, I am putting down my thoughts below:

1. I will try to explain this with an example:
   Let's say we have an application which is composed of different
   micro-services(say there are 3 micro-services m1, m2, m3) in the background.
   Horizontal scaling in particular is done for a specific micro-service. So if
   micro-service m2 needs to be scaled (may be bcoz demand for requirement it
   caters has increased a lot), we can add more servers to support m2. This way
   we have done horizontal scaling w.r.t m2.

   Now whenever 2 micro-services deployed on different servers need to interact
   on networks, distributed system come into play.
   From above example, m2 interacting with m1 or m3 interacting with m2 will be
   done over network and so will be considered distributed systems.

   Load balancer is used to support horizontal scaling and API calls are used to
   support distributed systems.

   So it can't be denied that both horizontal scaling and distributed system
   mostly come together.
2. It is strictly not correct though.
   Let's say we have only one service deployed on 5 different servers which are
   controlled using a load balancer. Also there is no database involved i.e., we
   don't need to store data but only few calculations is done and result is
   returned.

   In this case there is no interaction involved between different micro-services
   on different server although horizontal scaling is there.  (5 machines are
   supporting this service).

   So in this case horizontal scaling is there but it can't be called distributed
   system.
3. In vertical scaling all the components are running on single machine only. No
   inter communication involved. So vertical scaling shouldn't be considered
   distributed system.

Few resources I would like to mention:
https://medium.com/system-design-blog/key-characteristics-of-distributed-systems-781c4d92cce3

https://medium.com/@abhinavkorpal/scaling-horizontally-and-vertically-for-databases-a2aef778610c

Answer (score 0):

**Diffrence btw Distributed System & Horizontal Scalling:**

*Distributed systems have different components running on different machines, but in horizontal scaling, the same components are instantiated and run on different machines.

*In distributed systems, the components need to communicate through network calls but in horizontal scaling a machine can complete the whole task without any need to communicate with others.